# Is there a legends reason for Venator Class Star Destroyers having much bigger sections dedicated to hangars than Imperator Class Star Destroyers?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

So I was looking through the Incredible Cross Sections book and *Imperator*-Class Star Destroyers have two  side hangars each with two openings; one the outside and one to that big space where the Tantive IV was taken into in ANH, but *Venator* Star Destroyers have extremely similar hangars to the *Imperator*-Class with a underside opening and two side hangars but it also has a very large front hangar section with many hangars lining the bow of the ship and then the bow opens up allowing those ships to take off. Why did the Imperator-Class remove the bow hangars and just keep the side ones? Is there a reason for this? I want a Legends answer but I will take a Canon answer as a secondary answer.

Answer (score 4):

**The larger hangar was unnecessary.**

According to various Cross-Sections and other reference works, the standard fighter complement of a *Venator* was up to 420 fighter craft (192 V-wings, 192 Actises, and 36 ARC-170s), plus either 20 or 40 LAAT/i gunships (depending on the source) and some unspecified shuttles.

In contrast, the *Imperator* has various configurations of TIE fighters but always 72, plus perhaps a few dozen shuttles and landing craft of different types.

Given that the total number of small craft was cut severely, it's not really a big surprise that the hangar space and launching capacity was reduced as well.

**The bow hangar was a weak point.**

The large bow opening allows the *Venator* to launch a lot of fighters at once, but it's also a very large piece of the ship to be moving. It was slow to open and close, and was relatively easy for an enemy to attack. This might be a worthwhile tradeoff when you have 400 fighters to get into space all at once, but less so with the reduced fighter complement of the Imperial Star Destroyer.

Comment: Wait, people other than the jedi flew in "Jedi Interceptors"?

Comment: @SpyBoxOnline I think (I don't have the Cross-Sections, unfortunately) that the numbers were "on paper" specs rather than representing any one specific *Venator*, so it's possible that in general service, the Actis interceptors were replaced with something else. On the other hand, some sources indicate that there were non-Jedi versions of the Actis too.

Comment: My impression was that in the phase 1 era they used V-19 torrents for fighters, and Y-wings for bombers. Then in the phase 2 era they used ARC-170s for fighters and V-wings for bombing. Maybe it just meant that it could hold 192 small ships like that. Idk

Comment: @SpyBoxOnline Fwiw, Clone troopers fly Actises (Actes?) in some of the Legends-era Battlefront games, but it's unclear if it's just a game mechanic.

Comment: @MiloP yeah, i'm aware of that. I think it is because they couldn't come up with a "interceptor" ship for the Republic and chose the Eta Actis.